# How to fetch orders between date range using Shopify REST API?

Tags: rest, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api, shopify-api-node

I want to fetch orders between two dates using Shopify REST API, so-far I'm trying to achieve this via below endpoint

```
/admin/api/2020-07/orders.json?status=any&created_at_min=2022-04-14 00:00:00.000&created_at_max=2022-04-14 24:00:00.000
```

It returns total 2134 orders also it includes orders of **2022-04-15** But as per Shopify the total orders of **2022-04-14** are 2141.

However, when I consume the below mentioned order count endpoint using the same date range, it returns the correct count, just as Shopify shows. 2141

```
/admin/api/2020-07/orders/count.json?status=any&created_at_min=2022-04-14 00:00:00.000&created_at_max=2022-04-14 24:00:00.000
```

I am unable to understand why the same date parameters return different results.

Please advise how to achieve this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I also tried this case like you

(1) about API count orders

```
/admin/api/2020-07/orders/count.json?status=any&created_at_min=2022-04-14 00:00:00.000&created_at_max=2022-04-14 24:00:00.000
```

returns **2141** as **true**

(2) about API get orders

```
/admin/api/2020-07/orders.json?status=any&created_at_min=2022-04-14 00:00:00.000&created_at_max=2022-04-14 24:00:00.000
```

returns only **2134** which is **false**

Cause: because since_id is missing in first call api, Orders are not sorted by ID in ascending order

Solution: Add params **since_id=0** with the first API call (2)